# Volatile and more threads

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

I'm trying to understand the **volatile** keyword and its proper using. Looking at the Brian Goetz's article [Java theory and practice: Fixing the Java Memory Model](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/), I'm stuck on this example:

```
Map configOptions;
char[] configText;
volatile boolean initialized = false;

// In Thread A
configOptions = new HashMap();
configText = readConfigFile(fileName);
processConfigOptions(configText, configOptions);
initialized = true;

// In Thread B
while (!initialized) 
    sleep();
// use configOptions
```

The volatile variable above is used as a "guard" to indicate that a set of shared variables had been initialized.

I understand that since java 1.5, the **volatile** is strong enough to ensure that when thread B reads the volatile variable, it sees all variables that was visible to the thread A at the time the thread A writes to the volatile variable.

But what if there would be a thread C doing something like this:

```
// In Thread C
configOptions = new HashMap();
// put something to configOptions
```

My question: Is the **volatile** strong enough to ensure that when thread B reads the volatile variable, it sees **all** variables from all threads. Maybe some kind of flushing all caches? If not, then such a code with 3 threads is broken, right?

Comment: You're reading an article from 2004. The memory model has changed since.

Comment: It might be better to use Atmoic based objects, for example, AtomicBoolean

Comment: I think it has changed just in 2004.

Comment: @Kayaman I haven't seen it change since Java 1.5.  How has it changed since JSR 133?  I guess my better question, is how does it being written in 2004 invalidate the point being made?

Answer (score 4):

per the lang spec (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4):

> > A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

and

> > A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field.

so the volatile variable itself is safe from stale cache problems. Your questions is; "what about all other variables?" Well no, the volatile keyword only affects caching on the variable it is on: all other variables on those threads are unsynchronized.

Comment: "the volatile keyword only affects caching on the variable it is on" That's not true. Read the article I linked in my question. Especially the part called "What happens before what?"

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I will try to explain what **volatile** variables in Java is.

So, where to start?

1. Read and write operations with `volatile` variables are guaranteed to be atomic, even for 64-bit length variables. Note: `i++;` is not atomic because technically it is three variables.
2. Writing some value to `volatile` variable *happens-before* this value can be read from it. You can find lots of questions on SO about what *happens-before* is. **Important**: in JVM it is implemented with memory fences, `store` fence on writing and `load` fence on reading. From practical side that means when you read some value from it, you're guaranteed to see all values written to non-volatile variables before volatile write;
3. Values written to volatile variables are available to all CPUs and all threads at once, without any CPU caches.

Now, regarding your question.

> Is the volatile strong enough to ensure that when thread B reads the volatile variable, it sees all variables from all threads?

No. It is strong enough to ensure that when thread B read some value from `volatile` variable, it sees (will read) values from variables written **before** volatile write.

> Maybe some kind of flushing all caches?

Actually yes, on x86 architecture volatile write empties store order buffer, volatile read empties load order buffer. If you want more details on that, you may want to read answer for this question: [Java 8 Unsafe: xxxFence() instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603304/java-8-unsafe-xxxfence-instructions)

> If not, then such a code with 3 threads is broken, right?

This code works as intended (I guess), because thread `B` does volatile read prior to reading `configOptions` which guarantees its visibility.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the volatile strong enough to ensure that when thread B reads the
>   volatile variable, it sees all variables from all threads. Maybe some
>   kind of flushing all caches?

All variables from the volatile-writing-thread that are written prior to the volatile store will be visible.

So there is no 'flush all caches' magic.

> If not, then such a code with 3 threads is broken, right?

It could very well be broken with two threads if you do not synchronize correctly.  There is a reason the initialized flag is written to.  That effectively flushes all the writes that occurred on that thread.