# Can assertion fail on a single-CPU system if methods execute concurrently on different cores?

Tags: java, multithreading

***This only for learning the purpose, not intended for production usage***.

I'm learning about memory barriers and trying to experiment with it. I have ***single CPU***, ***multi-core system***. I found out that two new memory-barrier related methods were introduced since Java 8. Now I wrote the following code and not quite sure about its thread-safety

```
private static final Unsafe U = //...
private int a = 0;
private int b = 0;

void foo(){
    a = 1;
    U.storeFence();
    b = 1;
}

void bar(){
    while( b == 0) continue;
    U.loadFence();
    assert(a == 1);
}
```

Now suppose we have 2-core CPU and two threads `A` and `B`. `A` invokes `foo` and `B` invokes `bar`. The load-store barrier `Unsafe::loadFence` executes store buffer on each CPU core, therefore, thread `B` should get the actual value of `b`.

Can this assertion fail? Is it correct? If no, please could you clarify?

Comment: Isn't it for [codereview.se] ?

Comment: @AxelH Not exactly... I would like to improve my understanding of memory-barrier behavior on sinlge CPU system multicore.

Comment: Why do you want to use `Unsafe`? Wouldn't it be better to make it, well, safe?

Comment: You might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603304/java-8-unsafe-xxxfence-instructions

Comment: @AndyTurner Because I want to put memory barriers by myself. Is it possible to do another way? The question is not about unsafe anyway. I don't quite understand how memory barriers will do on the single cpu with mutiple cores. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Erik Yes, thanks much.

Comment: No, that code is not thread safe. You need to read the Java Memory Model specification (it's part of the JLS). There is no reason why a thread running method `bar` should even see the update to instance variable `b` done in method `foo` in a different thread. A compliant JVM is allowed to never show updates unless code is "correctly synchronized" (a term from the JMM, doesn't mean it needs to use `synchronized`, there are other ways too) and you are not using storeFence and loadFence to correctly synchronize the write to `b` either.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I know about memory model. The question is not about happens-before ordering and synchronization, but about CPU caches and store-buffers and how Unsafe API can help us working with it. Just experimenting...

Comment: Your question was "Is the code thread safe?" - it's not.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Incorrectly asked, yes. Fixed.

Comment: From programming point of view, different cores are different processors. They are counted separately in `Runtime.availableProcessors()`. And indeed they have separate L3 caches.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov But how do cores communicate? I mean they also support some cache coherency protocol? Like in case of inter-CPU communication?

Comment: Of course they support cache coherency, and even at higher speed than separate CPUs, but still a programmer cannot assume that cache content is always identical.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Very interesting. Since they use the same L1 and L2 caches, the protocol should be simpler than in multi-CPU system. Where can I read about it for x86 architecture? Or for core-i7....

Comment: @St.Antario sorry I did not investigate that issue and cannot help you.