# Unsafe: storeFence() & loadFence() vs volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, unsafe, memory-barriers

I'm checking [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23770837/12008421) on java fences, in which fences are used for following example, to ensure that concurrent thread can always read latest value updated from other threads:

```java
// CPU 0:
void shutDownWithFailure(void)
{
  failure = 1; // must use SOB as this is owned by CPU 1
  SFENCE // next instruction will execute after all SOBs are processed
  shutdown = 1; // can execute immediately as it is owned be CPU 0
}
// CPU1:
void workLoop(void)
{
  while (shutdown == 0) { ... }
  LFENCE // next instruction will execute after all LOBs are processed
  if (failure) { ...}
}
```

My question is, what's the advantage of using fences against `volatile`.
Taking above example, if I make both `failure` and `shutdown` **volatile**, it should achieve the same?

Comment: Pretty sure only `shutdown` needs to be `volatile` for this to work without separate fences.  You'd get release / acquire synchronization, guaranteeing that a reader seeing `shutdown == 1` would also see `failure == 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, it's all described in the [JEP 171](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/171) that is linked to that question, in the "Motivation" section at the top. To sum it up: it is meant to provide a documented way to access these mechanisms and to provide further implementations and extensions of the classes for concurrent access.

Doesn't mean to use them is always an advantage over `volatile`.

Comment: Thanks @cyberbrain. Would you know in which case will fence be the better choice than volatile?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know. In case it wasn't obvious: I'm no expert in that field, so I just gave an answer as vague as a politician to a TV reporter ;) Maybe this answer helps you better (tl;dr: it's all about performance): https://stackoverflow.com/a/60130907/2846138

Comment: @wayne: Separate fences can be useful as part of a SeqLock, where you need to stop the 2nd atomic load of the sequence number from reordering with *earlier* non-atomic loads, opposite of what acquire semantics gives you.  e.g. in C++ [Implementing 64 bit atomic counter with 32 bit atomics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54611003).  (But note that despite your use of the LFENCE name, you don't actually want an x86 `lfence` instruction; it's not useful for memory ordering of normal loads.  A JVM would only need to make sure x86 load instructions are in the right order on strongly-ordered x86.)

Comment: [Using JDK 9 Memory Order Modes](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/j9mm.html) is a good read. I've used weaker ordering when piggybacking on another fence, e.g. writes only occur under a lock and flush on its release. Trying to optimize at this level is error prone (e.g. [JDK-8078490](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8078490), [cats-effect's naivety](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFkpmFt61Jo)). I try to ensure my usages are benign or else use stronger modes as the performance change is miniscule.