# LOCK prefix of Intel instruction. What is the point?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, parallel-processing, intel

I read the Intel manual and found there is a lock prefix for instructions, which can prevent processors writing to the same memory location at the same time. I am quite excited about it. I guess it could be used as hardware mutex. So I wrote a piece of code to have a shot. The result is quite frustrating. The lock does not support MOV or LEA instructions. The manual says LOCK only supports ADD, ADC, AND, BTC, BTR, BTS, CMPXCHG, CMPXCH8B, DEC, INC, NEG, NOT, OR, SBB, SUB, XOR, XADD, and XCHG. What is more, if the LOCK prefix is used with one of these instructions and the source operand is a memory operand, an undefined opcode exception (#UD) may be generated.

I wonder why so many limitations, so many restrictions make LOCK seem useless. I cannot use it to guarantee a general write operation not have dirty data or other problems caused by parallelism.

E.g. I wrote code ++(*p) in C. p is pointer to a shared memory. The corresponding assembly is like:

```
movl    28(%esp), %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
leal    1(%eax), %edx
movl    28(%esp), %eax
movl    %edx, (%eax)
```

I added "lock" before "movl" and "leal", but the processor complains "Invalid Instruction". :-( I guess the only way to make the write operations serialized is to use software mutex, right?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetch-and-add

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

Comment: A `movl` to an aligned address is always atomic, so lock would make no difference at all.

Comment: If these "restrictions" did not exist, the additional uses would all be useless anyway.

Comment: BTW, there is a problem with your code: Even if each instruction was carried out with a bus-lock, the code would still not be thread safe, as it could be interrupted between any instruction. You want to have the whole instruction block run by at maximum one thread a a time. You need a completely different approach to this - a mutex or similar. To do this, you basically need to surround the code with locking/unlocking code - which involves instructions like "lock cmpxchg" et al

Comment: @drhirsch - I don't think aligned movs are *guaranteed* atomic.  It's certainly not atomic on the 8088 (for 16-bit) or 386SX (for 32-bit) operations.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: They are guaranteed atomic on all processors since 486, to be more specific. I just assumed that we were talking about processors younger than 20 years. See the Intel System Programming Guide Chapter 8.1.1 "The Intel486 processor (and newer processors since) guarantees that the following
basic memory operations will always be carried out atomically:
• Reading or writing a byte
• Reading or writing a word aligned on a 16-bit boundary
• Reading or writing a doubleword aligned on a 32-bit boundary" etc.

Comment: If you want to use a `lock`ed instruction as just a memory barrier (on a CPU that doesn't support `MFENCE`, or where `MFENCE` is slower than a locked instruction), you can just `lock add $0, %(esp)`, which is otherwise a no-op (except clobbering flags) and does its read-modify-write locked cycle on memory that's very likely hot in L1 cache and NOT on another core.  Other than that, this question seems to entirely miss the point of the `lock` prefix.  It's for atomic read-modify-writes.  The full-memory-barrier is just a side-effect, but x86 didn't have a separate barrier insn until `mfence`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is x86 CMPXCHG atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837731/is-x86-cmpxchg-atomic)

Comment: @PeterCordes should this be dupped hammered, seems we have a lot of these also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020128/why-we-need-lock-prefix-before-cmpxchg

Comment: @EvanCarroll: This isn't a duplicate: it seems to be asking what the point of `lock` is if it can't be used to make a `mov` atomic.  (But it's totally mixed up about making the whole RMW atomic vs. making one `mov` atomic.) 
 It's not asking about CMPXCHG; if anything the instruction they want is `lock add` or `lock xadd`.  But yes, I duphammered your 2nd link, like I tried to years ago before I had the rep to do it alone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I certainly would not call `lock` useless. `lock cmpxchg` is the standard way to perform [compare-and-swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap), which is the basic building block of many synchronization algorithms.

Also, see [fetch-and-add](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetch-and-add).

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of `lock` is to make operations **atomic**, not serialized. In this way the CPU cannot be preempted before the operation takes effect.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not very sure about these terminologies. I guess atomic means the operation will be done in a whole, no interruption, otherwise canceled. In this problem, even if "lock add" is done in an atomic manner, if does not mean other processor cannot access that memory location stealthily at the same time. So what "lock" is doing is to prevent parallel access to the same memory location. I guess this is called serialized, making every thread access the memory one by one.

Comment: Atomic operations are primitives used *for* serialization, but they are not serialized themselves; serialization refers to multiple entities *performing the same operation* one at a time, whereas atomic operations preform an arbitrary operation in one discrete motion, undisturbed by others.

Answer (score 3):

The x86 processors are known for a hairy design with lots of features, lots of rules, and even more exceptions to all those rules.  This is related to the long history to the family.

When compilers or people are using `LOCK`, they are always using it with all its limitations, often on data specially introduced to perform synchronization between threads, as opposed to application data that the algorithms eventually manipulate.  One then adapts the thread synchronization protocols to what `LOCK` can do for them, rather than vice versa.

The general type of instruction you seem to look for is called [memory barriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier).  Indeed,  x86 has several "modern" instructions from this family (MFENCE, LFENCE, SFENCE).  They are full fence, load fence, and store fence, respectively.  However, their importance in the instruction set is limited to [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions), because Intel guarantees serialization of writes on the traditional part of the instruction set, and that is pretty much the reason why this aged architecture is quite an easy target for multithreaded programming.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232660/which-is-a-better-write-barrier-on-x86-lockaddl-or-xchgl) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

It is useful when, on a multiprocessor machine, there are two concurrent processes that are using the same data but they can't modify it simultaneously.

When one of the processes is modifying the data, it uses lock on the modifying instruction so that, when the second process tries to modify it, it has to wait for the first one to finish its job before being able to do its own on its turn.

I hope this will help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you provide, you can use a `lock` prefix with an `inc` instruction like this (assuming `p` is located in `%eax`):

```
lock inc (%eax)
```

In more general cases, you have to use locks though.