# How does Linux kernel flush_write_buffers() work on x86?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, dma

The following code is from `include/asm-i386/io.h`, and it is invoked from `dma_map_single()`. My understanding is that `flush_write_buffers()` is supposed to flush CPU memory cache before mapping the memory for DMA. But how does this assembly code flush CPU cache?

```
static inline void flush_write_buffers(void)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("lock; addl $0,0(%%esp)": : :"memory");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The Intel Pentium Pro processors had a bug wherein a store to a memory location of type UC may be reordered with earlier memory accesses to locations of type WC, which violates the x86 memory consistency model. As a workaround, a correctly implemented memory serializing instruction can be used just before the UC store. On the Pentium Pro processors, any the following would do the job: (1) `cpuid`, (2) a UC load, or (3) a `lock`-prefixed instruction.

The `flush_write_buffers` in the Linux kernel uses a `lock`-prefixed instruction for precisely this purpose. `cpuid` is the most expensive and unnecessary for this purpose. A UC load requires a memory location of type UC, which is a little inconvenient in general. Hence, the choice of using a `lock`-prefixed instruction.

As the name of the function indicates, the purpose of it is to wait until all pending writes in the write buffer (a.k.a. store buffer, in this context) become globally observable. The caches are not affected.

This bug only affects Pentium Pro and the kernel had to be compiled with `CONFIG_X86_PPRO_FENCE` for the workaround to be enabled. It was difficult, though, to be sure that the workaround is used in all the places in the kernel where it's supposed to be used. Moreover, `CONFIG_X86_PPRO_FENCE` didn't only affect the operation of `flush_write_buffers`, but also other constructs, so it can cause significant performance degradation. Eventually, it was [dropped](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/935093/) from the kernel starting with v4.16-rc7.

Answer (score 5):

What you are seeing is a [memory fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier). What that instruction does is guaranteeing that all preceding load and store instructions become globally visible to any following load or store instructions.

A fence acts as a barrier, with the effect of flushing CPU buffers (note: buffers, not cache, that's a different thing) because data that was waiting to be written needs to be made globally available right away before continuing, in order to ensure that successive instructions will fetch the correct data.

This function was introduced to get around an hardware problem in an old family of Intel CPUs, namely the Pentium Pro (1995-98), which caused memory access operations under specific circumstances to be executed in the wrong order.

Nowdays the canonical way of applying a fence in x86 is through the use of the [`mfence`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mfence), [`lfence`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lfence) or [`sfence`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sfence) instructions (depending oh the type of fence needed), but those were only later added (with SSE and SSE2). On the Pentium Pro, no such instructions were available.

The `lock` instruction is really just an instruction prefix, so this:

```
lock
addl $0,0(%esp)
```

Is actually a "locked `add`".

The `lock` prefix is used for opcodes that perform a read-modify-write operation to make them atomic. When applying `lock add $0, 0(%esp)`, in order for the instruction to be atomic and therefore for the result to be immediately globally visible, a load+store fence is implicitly applied. The top of the stack is always readable and writable, and adding 0 is a no-op, so there's no need to pass a valid address to the function. This workaround therefore permits the correct serialization of memory access, and it's the fastest type of instruction to accomplish the goal on the Intel Pentium Pro.

---

See also these other posts:

- [Which is a better write barrier on x86: lock+addl or xchgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232660/which-is-a-better-write-barrier-on-x86-lockaddl-or-xchgl)
- [What does the “lock” instruction mean in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891067/what-does-the-lock-instruction-mean-in-x86-assembly)
- [Does lock xchg have the same behavior as mfence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409297/does-lock-xchg-have-the-same-behavior-as-mfence)

Comment: I think the question is really about what the function `flush_write_buffers` does rather than the lock-prefixed instruction, which are two entirely different questions with essentially different answers. But other than that, there are several inaccurate statements. The biggest one is "the lock add instruction was just chosen instead of mfence for performance reasons..." Not only this point is too inaccurate, but also irrelevant because `mfence` is not supported on the processors where `flush_write_buffers` is needed.

Comment: @HadiBrais thanks for the pointer, you are indeed right, corrected.

Comment: If you're going to go into detail about why `lock add...`, it's worth mentioning that `x += 0` doesn't modify `x`, and that `0(%esp)` is the "top of stack" which is highly likely to be already exclusively owned in L1d cache and not shared with any other cores.  Probably one of those links already covers that but a summary wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @PeterCordes I had that in my previous version of the answer, but really the fact that add 0 is a no-op is obvious and doesn't add much to the explanation. I'll add a parenthesis.

Comment: *the atomicity of the operation isn't really needed* potentially not true: this might be the address of a local that we've passed to another thread.  Unlikely but possible.  The point is that you want need to pick some memory somewhere, and `0(%esp)` is always writeable so it's safe to pick, and also usually efficient.